# WCF service error when using MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: mysql, wcf

I have a fully functional WCF webservice hosted in iis7 on Win Server 2008 machine. The problem is when I try to implement mysql calls to a method in the service. The method works fine when debugging in vs, all the mysql methods and the call to the database works as it should, but when deploying it to the server I get

> "The server encountered an error processing the request"

If I remove everything in the method but for example:

```
string connStr = "{connection details}";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

and try to run the service, I still get the same error...

I've run out of ideas and really need your help!

Answer (score 0):

2 random shots in the dark:

1. Check the Event Viewer application log on the server.  It will probably give you the root cause to your error.
2. Are the MySQL binaries 32-bit?  If the IIS application pool doesn't allow 32 bit libraries it will bomb out.  There is an option in the app pool to allow 32 bit binaries.

Comment: 1. I have checked the log but it doesn't give me any valuable info other than bad request

2. I suppose the binaries are 32 bit, but the os is 32 bit as well

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with this very problem I finally found a solution.

Find your MySql.Data reference in your References folder, click on it, and look at its properties.

Find the "Copy Local" property and make sure this is set to true.